# Implement the Select for a custom LINQ provider

Tags: linq, provider

I understand pretty the way implementing Linq to something however there is a little problem that I encounter here is the situation, I'm implementing a Linq to Tree object the tree it self is simple Tree implementation so I started by creating the Queryable object

```
public class TreeContext<T> : IOrderedQueryable where T :IComparable<T>
{
    private Tree<T> _root;
    private Expression _expression;
    private IQueryProvider _provider;

    public TreeContext(Tree<T> root)
    {
        _root = root;
        Provider = new TreeProvider<T>(_root);
    }

    public TreeContext(IQueryProvider provider, Expression expression)
    {
        Provider = provider;
        Expression = expression;
    }
    #region Model 

    public IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TResult>(Func<T,TResult> predicate)
    {

        var param = predicate.Method.GetParameters()[0];

        

        
        return null;
    }

  

    public IEnumerable<T> Where(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        

        
        Provider.Execute<IEnumerable>(Expression);

        return null;
    }
    #endregion



    public Expression Expression 
    { 
        private set { _expression = value; } 
        get { return _expression; } 
    }

    public Type ElementType => typeof(T);

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        private set { _provider = value; }
        get { return _provider; }
    }

   

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    => GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    =>Provider.Execute<IEnumerable>(Expression).GetEnumerator();
    
}
```

Then I implemented the QueryProvider and here resides the problem, exactly at the select method implementation

```
public class TreeProvider<T> : IQueryProvider where T:IComparable<T>
{
    private Tree<T> _root;

    public TreeProvider(Tree<T> root)
    => _root = root;


    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
      => new TreeContext<T>(this, expression);

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
      =>throw new NotImplementedException();


    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    => new TreeQueryContext<T>(_root).Execute(expression);
 

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        throw  new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The select implementation is not provided for this custom provider so that I can write a request like
from el in context select el

I added a method select

IEnumerable Select<T,TResult>(Func<T,TResult> selector)

The problem is that I didn't find a way the transform this selector to an expression so that I pass it to the execute method of the QueryProvider

Maybe I didn't understand well how to develop a custom LINQ to custom provider and I didn't find any good and complete tutorial on that in C#

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create LINQ Provider - you have to deal always with Expression Tree to create and parse query.

`Select` and `Where` in your `TreeContext` are not needed at all. Standard LINQ Extensions has these methods and will automatically prepare Expression Tree for you. Focus on `TreeProvider` implementation.

Since you are new in this area, I would suggest to base your LINQ Provider on [Relinq](https://github.com/re-motion/Relinq). It will simplify your life from start and will show possible ways for implementation. It has base classes for Provider and Query implementation, but it is not required to derive from them.

Just try

```
var queryParser = new QueryParser(new ExpressionTreeParser(
                ExpressionTreeParser.CreateDefaultNodeTypeProvider(),
                ExpressionTreeParser.CreateDefaultProcessor(
                    ExpressionTransformerRegistry.CreateDefault(),
                    null)));

var queryModel = parser.GetParsedQuery(expression);
```

And Relinq will give you `QueryModel`, which is much easier to parse.

Comment: Thank you Svyatoslav Danyliv I need to give it a try, you said Select and Where in your TreeContext are not needed at all I understand that they are provided as extensions method by IQueryable interface but when I try this

var query = from el in treecontext select el  it responds me that there is not corresponding select implemntation for treecontext I didn't understand that point

Comment: Your have to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your .cs file